# Pyspark: How to chain Column.when() using a dictionary with reduce?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, functional-programming

I'm trying to get conditions from a dictionary in a chain of `when()` functions using `reduce()` to pass in the end to a `dataframe.withColumn()`.

for example:

```
conditions = {
    "0": (col("a") == 1.0) & (col("b") != 1.0),
    "1": (col("c") == 1.0) & (col("d") == 1.0)
}
```

using reduce() I implemented this:

```
when_stats = reduce(lambda key, value: when(conditions[key], lit(key)), conditions)
```

and later using it in withColumn():

```
df2 = df1.withColumn(result, when_stats)
```

The problem is that it only takes the first condition which is "0" and doesn't chain the second one.
printing 'when_stats' gives me:

```
Column<'CASE WHEN ((a = 1.0) AND (NOT (b = 1.0))) THEN 0 END'>
```

When I add a 3rd condition it throws an error and doesn't work:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'Column'

So the question is, how can I loop through the dictionary and create the complete `when().when().when()`... ? Is there a better solution specially if I want to have `otherwise()` in the end?

Comment: What is `rang_rules`?  do you mean `conditions`?

Comment: yes, corrected it :)

Comment: You can try `when_stats = reduce(lambda prev, key: when(conditions[key], lit(key)) if prev is None else prev.when(conditions[key], lit(key)), conditions, None)`. and `when_stats.otherwise(lit('othervalue'))`.  There may be a better way though.

Comment: Thank you this worked. The solution from 'blackbishop' is similar but kinda more simple :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `reduce` with dict object, you're actually iterating over the keys of the dict. So the lambda function takes `acc` the accumulator and `key` the actual key being processed.

You can use this instead:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

conditions = {
    "0": (F.col("a") == 1.0) & (F.col("b") != 1.0),
    "1": (F.col("c") == 1.0) & (F.col("d") == 1.0)
}

when_stats = reduce(
    lambda acc, key: acc.when(conditions[key], key),
    conditions,
    F
) #.otherwise("default_value")

print(when_stats)
# Column<'CASE WHEN ((a = 1.0) AND (NOT (b = 1.0))) THEN 0 WHEN ((c = 1.0) AND (d = 1.0)) THEN 1 END'>
```

Comment: this worked great, nice idea with the F in the initializer, thank you :)